# Building a function dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, elasticsearch

I'm using a query builder called [Body Builder](https://bodybuilder.js.org/)
I need the builder to work based on the amount of filters selected.
So the default filter for a specific list type looks like:

```js
bodybuilder()
    .aggregations('terms', 'listingType.keyword', 'Type')
    .build()
```

Which works as expected. I have the aggregation bucket I need.

What If an item was selected? I'd want to add that filter to it.

This is what I want it to look like:

```js
bodybuilder()
    .addFilter('term', 'itemTypeId', 2)
    .aggregations('terms', 'listingType.keyword', 'Type')
    .build()
```

Or if multiple items were selected then..

```js
bodybuilder()
    .addFilter('term', 'itemTypeId', id)
    .addFilter('term', 'moo.keyword', moo)
    .addFilter('term', 'make.keyword', make)
    .aggregations('terms', 'listingType.keyword', 'Type')
    .build()
```

I have an array of selected filters. I figured I could do something like:

```js
const activeFilters = [{type: 'make.keyword, value: 'SAMSUNG'}, {type: 'moo.keyword', value: 'moo'}]

if (activeFilters) {
    activeFilters.map(item => {
        addFilter(item.type, item.value)
    }
}

//OR

bodybuilder()
    activeFilters.map(item => addFilter(item.type, item.value)
    .aggregation('terms' , 'listingType.keyword', 'Type')
    .build()
```

Something along those lines. Any recommendations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, you can do something like this:

```
const activeFilters = [{type: 'make.keyword, value: 'SAMSUNG'}, {type: 'moo.keyword', value: 'moo'}];
let query = bodybuilder();

activeFilters.forEach(filter => {
  query = query.addFilter('term', filter.type, filter.value);
});

query.aggregation('terms' , 'listingType.keyword', 'Type')
    .build()
```

The idea is to keep a reference to the return value instead of chaining the calls.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using reduce for this case:

```
const query = activeFilters.reduce((query, filter) => query.addFilter('term', filter.type, filter.value), bodybuilder())
    .aggregation('terms' , 'listingType.keyword', 'Type')
    .build();
```

There's one problem with Titus's solution - you cannot reassign `const`, so in current form, it most probably won't work. If you are going to use his code you need to change `query` variable declaration from `const` to `let`.

Comment: i forgot to make that suggestion, but you're correct, i did have to change `const` to `let` to make it work. good call!